# What is the analogue of CTRL + ARROW in cygwin bash?

Tags: bash, cygwin

In Windows applications in general, we can step over words by using `CTRL+ ->` to step right and `CTRL + <-` to step left. But in Bash, those combinations print `3C` and `3D` correspondingly. Is there the analogue of such combination in Cygwin Bash at all?

Comment: This is not an issue of bash, but of the terminal emulation you use. All the shortcuts in there are configurable. So probably your question is: where can I control that? The answer: obviously depends on which terminal emulation you use...

Comment: @arkascha Maybe... I just don't have too much experience in terminal scripting. So, now I'm using cygwin's terminal on windows 8, is there such facitily?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have no idea about that. Never used it, never had a reason to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://superuser.com/questions/488157/how-do-i-make-ctrl-arrow-keys-move-forward-backward-a-word-at-a-time-in-cygwin-b/488158

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the shell, terminal, and your `.initrc`, but by default, <kbd>Alt + F</kbd> for *forward* and <kbd>Alt + B</kbd> for *backward* should work.

Check `forward-word` and `backward-word` in `bind -p`.